# Scala repeated parameters and parameters in List confusion

Tags: scala

I'm using Scala 2.9

I have a class:

```
    class Queue[T] private( private val heading: List[T], private val trailing: List[T] ) {
        def this( a: T* ) = this( a.toList, Nil )

        private def mirror = {
            if ( heading.isEmpty ) {
                new Queue[T]( trailing.reverse, Nil )
            } else this
        }

        def head = {
            val q = mirror
            if ( q.heading.isEmpty ) None else new Some(q.heading.head)
        }

        def tail = {
            val q = mirror
            if ( q.heading.isEmpty ) q else new Queue[T]( q.heading.tail, trailing )
        }

        def enqueue( a: T ) = {
            new Queue[T]( heading, a::trailing )
        }
    }
```

In method enqueue, if I write `new Queue( heading, a::trailing )`(leaving out the type parameter [T]), the code won't compile and scalac complaints about "ambiguous reference to overloaded definition, both constructor Queue in class Queue of type (a: T*)Queue[T] and constructor Queue in class Queue of type (heading: List[T], trailing: List[T])Queue[T] match argument types (List[T],List[T])".

So why is it necessary to explicitly specify the type parameter`[T]` otherwise Scala will treat the two separate Lists as a whole for a repeat parameter? I think it has something to do with type inference, could someone please explain it?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't give the type argument, the compiler could either infer `T` (for the primary constructor) or `List[T]` (for the auxiliary constructor).

Comment: Thank you Heiko. Apparently I failed to realize that the auxiliary constructor can be applied for 2 List[U] with T=List[U].

Answer (score 2):

Heiko's answer is correct, but to clarify this a bit, the `T` in `enqueue` is a different `T` than the one in the context of the `Queue` you are about to create and has therefore to be inferred which leads to the ambiguity. Why do you have 2 constructors anyway? I would suggest you to use a companion for your constructor for the outer world:

```
class Queue[T] private( private val heading: List[T], private val trailing: List[T]) { /* ... */}

object Queue {
  def apply[T](xs: T*) = new Queue(xs.toList, Nil)
}
```

Comment: Thank you drexin. I do not quite understand your point that _the T in enqueue is a different T than the one in the context of the Queue you are about to create_ I think the T in enqueue is the same as the T in `class Queue[T]`, that's why `a::trailing` does not give an error. And I'd better make Queue a Trait and use object as a factory to the outer world. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: The `T` in `new Queue` is not specified, so the compiler tries to infer it. As you have two constructor that match your `List[T], List[T]` constructor the compiler can not infer the constructor you want to call. When you pass in the `T` from your current context explicitly, the compiler knows, that the `T` of the new instance should be your old `T` and not `List[T]`.